# Update textInput values when user changes an ID

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to get a Shiny app built that updates predictions based on changes in variables from textInput. I built a smaller version using mtcars into a dataframe.

```
data(mtcars)
df <- data.frame(Color=c(rep("red",5),rep("grey",10),rep("white",10),rep("black",5),rep("chrome",2)))
df$Model <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$Model <- rownames(mtcars)
df_merged <- merge(mtcars,df)
head(df_merged)

lm.model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat, df_merged)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("What if scenarios"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                 
                 # Input: text input for the number of texts to be reviewed ----
                 
                 actionButton("hidden", "Toggle"),
                 
                 selectInput(inputId = "model",
                           label = "Model:",
                           value = unique(df_merged$model)), 
                 

                 textInput(inputId = "cyl",
                           label = "CYL:",
                           value = df_merged$cyl),
                 
                 textInput(inputId = "disp",
                           label = "disp",
                           value = df_merged$disp),
                 
                 textInput(inputId = "hp",
                           label = "HP",
                           value = df_merged$hp),
                 
                 textInput(inputId = "drat",
                           label = "drat",
                           value = df_merged$drat),
                 
                 
                 
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot"),
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "comparisonTable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    
    model <- input$model
    mpg <- as.numeric(input$mpg)
    cyl <- as.numeric(input$cyl)
    disp <- as.numeric(input$disp)
    hp <- as.numeric(input$hp)
    drat <- as.numeric(input$drat)
    
    input_dat <- tibble(mpg = mpg,
                        cyl = cyl,
                        disp = disp,
                        hp = hp,
                        drat = drat)
    
    setDT(input_dat)
    
    pred <- predict.lm(model, input_dat)
    
    return(new dt with pred populated)
    
  })
    
    output$comparisonTable <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
      DT::datatable(plotData(), 
                    rownames= FALSE, 
                    options = list(bFilter = 0,     #remove filter
                                   bLengthChange=0,
                                   scrollX = TRUE))#remove number of items to display dropdown
    })
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This isn't a total 1:1 example since my actual app is pulling from somewhere else and not just a linear model, so after all the data is processed through the inputs the prediction is already generated in the data table that's returned at the end of the server function.

I am trying to get it to update the populated text inputs when you change the model to their respective variables (i.e. when you change from an AMC Javelin to a Datsun 710, the mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat text changes to match) and a new prediction is generated in the new dataframe.

I know the issue is the fact that the df is loaded outside of the app entirely but I don't know how to make prepopulate inputs in text-input outside of the UI, so that is what I'm looking for help on.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a little unclear, but have you looked into using `updateTextInput`?

Comment: I have, but unfortunately I get a little mushbrained the example in Shiny documentation, mainly around the "controller" input. The idea though is when I change the model input, all the other inputs (mpg, cyl, disp in this example) will change as well. Right now it is set up so those mpg, cyl, and disp inputs are remaining with the first one that is loaded.

I also realized I wasn't super clear. When I loaded the data at the start before the UI, it is filtered out (only because the actual app is a large data set) and this was the only way I can think of to pre-load default data.

Comment: Perhaps add an `observeEvent(somedata(), { req(somedata()); ch <- unique(somedata()$cyl); sel <- input$CYL; if (!sel %in% ch) sel <- ch[1]; updateTextInput(session, "CYL", choices = ch, selected = sel); })`

Comment: So I was able to get an observeEvent() and updateTextInput() to work so the sidebar is dynamic, but now I can't get it to update the data table and push out new predictions with a user input since the observeEvent is tied to the change in drop down. Tried to make a separate eventReactive item and tried to have it run on a separate page but it double counted some features and threw the whole prediction off.

Comment: Not really sure, tbh. BTW, why do you use `textInput(.)` and then `as.numeric(input$..)`? Why not just `numericInput(.., step=1)` with no need for `as.numeric`?

Comment: This I did change, but is kind of a non-issue to what I need solved which is having Shiny be able to populate default inputs based on the observation of an event (in this example the change in car model) and run a prediction on those default OR run an updated prediction on user inputs.